# Путь к файлу PHP

Tags: файлы, php

Ситуация следующая: напсиал такой код

```
include("/../../block.php");
```

Пишет не существует файла. Я написал иначе:

```
include("../../block.php");
```

Всё равно не найден файл. Решил иначе:

```
include(__DIR\__."/../../block.php");
```

Бинго! Рабоатет! Так почему так случилось? Вроде бы варианты идентичны. Из-за чего проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> include("/../../block.php");

Вы указали путь относительно корневого каталога

> include("../../block.php");

Это по идее должно работать, но конфигурация вашего сервера не позволяет, по этому пользуйтесь конструкцией

```
include("./../../block.php");
```

И всем будет проще
./ - текущий каталог (в котором ваш файл)

Comment: К сожалению не работает, похоже отключена вообще возможность такой записи, какая штука в конфиге включет это?

Answer (score 3):

> `__DIR__` -  Директория файла. Если используется внутри подключаемого файла, то возвращается директория этого файла. Это эквивалентно вызову dirname(**FILE**). Возвращаемое имя директории не оканчивается на слэш, за исключением корневой директории (добавлена в PHP 5.3.0.)

т.е. это не обозначает текущую директорию. Когда вы инклудите по относительным ссылкам, идет подключение по установленной директории (которая может отличаться от директории файла)

Answer (score 2):

А вообще, есть хорошая штука `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`